# ListFeatureClasses isn't returning anything in GDB

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase

I am writing a script that performs a series of operations on line, point, and polygon files in my file geodatabase matched through a unique number in their filenames. My geodatabase looks like this:

- sd_junc_1.shp (point file)
- sd_junc_2.shp (point file)
- sd_test_1.shp (polygon file)
- sd_test_2.shp (polygon file)
- sd_test_streets_1.shp (line file)
- sd_test_streets_2.shp (line file)

I'd like to be able to find each file that ends with the number 1, perform the operations, then do the same operations on files that end with 2, and so on. Here's the code I have so far:

```
#import os
import os

# Local environment
arcpy.env.workspace = r"E:\LA 221\Subdivisions\Wake County\wakecounty.gdb"

# Initialize counter
counter = 1

# Loop

while counter < 6:
    counter_string = str(counter)
    # Create variables from feature classes in the GDB
    Clipped_streets = [fc for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type = 'Line') if os.path.splitext(fc)[0].endswith(counter_string)]
    Clipped_streets_Junc = [fc for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type = 'Point') if os.path.splitext(fc)[0].endswith(counter_string)]
    Subdivision_boundary = [fc for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type = 'Polygon') if os.path.splitext(fc)[0].endswith(counter_string)]

    # Process: Select access points
    selected_access = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(Clipped_streets_Junc, "BOUNDARY_TOUCHES", Subdivision_boundary, "", "NEW_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")
```

This code fails at the last line (selected_access = ...) with the error "RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool" and I'm guessing because there is nothing in the "Clipped_streets_Junc" and "Subdivision_boundary" variables.

Comment: You can add a wildcard in ListFeatureClasses. Something like this "*_%s"%counter  . Also you are passing the SelectLayerByLocation a list object. I believe it needs a path to a feature class or a layer object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So should I not use ListFeatureClasses to get my files that I can pass to SelectLayerByLocation? Or is there a way to make the list object into a path to a feature class?

Comment: Select Layer by Location requires one layer, not a list of feature classes.  You may need to loop through the Clipped_Streets list and Make Feature Layer to convert to layer before running the select

Comment: You ***cannot*** have *shapefiles* in a geodatabase.  so your problem set-up doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You're right, they are feature classes. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/189555/edit) the question to remove the ".shp" extensions and change "file" references to "table".